# Where to get a simple WPF DataGrid template?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to understand and modificate DataGrid. Where to get a simple or standart template for starting? I found only Silverlight DataGrid on msdn and it is not match, because it use specific controls like a

```
<localprimitives:DataGridFrozenGrid Name="Root">
```

Comment: Add `DataGrid` into xaml of your window, right click, "Edit template"...

Comment: @Sinatr I didn't know about this functuion. Thx.

Comment: @Sinatr Why VS dont create a template with VisualStates?

Comment: No idea what you mean. You can ask a new question unless it's too dumb (e.g. there are no visual states at all in template you are trying to modify, obviously you have to do it yourself) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DataGrid` is by far a *simple* control. You can find the `ControlTemplate` in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff506248(v=vs.100).aspx).

Alternatively, as Sinatr has pointed out, you can use the built in editing functionality in Visual Studio by adding a control to your view (A `DataGrid` in this case), right clicking on it and selecting *"Edit Template"*.

Comment: I know that DataGrid is not simple control. Thats why i want to understand it. Google didnt give me link to this article.